# Google Spreadsheet Script. Only work for one sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that I found online and it works as needed, but it works for all my sheets or the tabs at the bottom if you want to call them. I want it to work

```
function onEdit(event) 
{
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var eventRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var eventColumn = eventRange.getLastColumn();

    if (eventColumn == 1) 
    {
      var stampRange = eventRange.offset(0,10);
      stampRange.setValue(new Date());

    }
}
```

This is the original code, I tried adding in line 4 the following but i can't get it to work. I'm not experienced with javascript but I need your help as i'm trying my best. Thank you.

`if(sheet.match(/*.13/)){`

This is the line I added. Based on my reading online, the script should works only if the sheet name ends with 13. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but `sheet` is a Sheet Object, while `.match()` is a String method. Use the `Sheet.getSheetName()` method to get the name of the sheet (the words on the tab).

In an `onEdit()`, you usually want to bail out without investing much processing time, so you should put the test for the sheet name as early as possible.

If you want to match `"Sheet13"` exactly, you should test for just that - because your regex will also match "Apollo13" and "a13a", for example.

```
function onEdit(event) 
{
    var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();

    if (sheetName.match(/.13/) == null)
      // These aren't the droids you're looking for...
      return;

    var eventRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
    var eventColumn = eventRange.getLastColumn();

    if (eventColumn == 1) 
    {
      var stampRange = eventRange.offset(0,10);
      stampRange.setValue(new Date());

    }
}
```